# Groovy-Eclipse plug in problems

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I am using Eclipse and working on a project where a java file calls a .groovy code. But the build fails, saying that the .groovy class cannot be resolved. I searched a lot for the solution, but could not find one. I included all the necessary jars. Somewhere I read an article that said to update the Eclipse-Groovy plug in. I did that as well. But still the same problem exists. I am using Eclipse Juno 4.2 and Groovy compiler version 2.0.6.xx.

I am really stuck at this. I need to fix this, and proceed with my project. Please help me guys.

Comment: I need some more information.  Any errors in the error log? Is the groovy file on the build path?  Are you using maven or gradle? Is your project a groovy project (do you see a 'Gr' on the project icon?

Comment: The error says 'BuildJSONBuilder cannot be resolved', where BuildJSONBuilder is the groovy file(BuildJSONBuilder.groovy). The groovy file is src/main/groovy directory, and I have that directory in my build path. I am using maven. Nope it is not a groovy project(I dont see Gr on the project icon).

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the project -> Configure -> Convert to Groovy project.

Are you sure this project is not a maven or gradle project?  The src/main/groovy source folder implies one of those.

Comment: Sorry my bad. It is a maven project. Not a groovy project

Comment: Should I convert it to a groovy project still??

Comment: You need to install  the groovy-eclipse configurator for m2e.  It is available on the groovy-eclipse update site.  Once this is installed, it will automatically configure your groovy support

Comment: The update site for Eclipse 4.2 is http://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e4.2/. I installed the groovy eclipse plugin from there. I am sorry I am a newbie. What else do I need to do in order to make it work?